# Is core data implementing data mapper pattern?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, datamapper

I know that core data should not be considered as ORM but it still offers the functionality that is similar to ORM. Just curious, is it implementing data mapper pattern? I know "The Data Mapper is a layer of software that separates the in-memory objects from the database. Its responsibility is to transfer data between the two and also to isolate them from each other." (Martin Fowler). IMHO context manager handles all SQL stuff into one transaction, so it's very performance wise design and IMHO core data might be considered implementing data mapper pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One year latter, I will contribute with my two cents

I am not an ORM expert and just recently started something using a Data Mapper, but as a long time Core Data user I can say that no. The main objective of this pattern is having a clear cut of a domain object from all database related operations.

Once I start writing unit tests, the first thing I notice is that I must load a database, even if it is just some in memory store, but I do must load one. Also there are no mappers for each class, I have no control about how each relation is stored.

Core Data loads lots of meta information about your object graph and forces some structure to them. Although you can change the persistent store and bake something of your own, you will have lots of restrictions about how to do it, with a clear "relational" feeling to it.

The idea is good, we might say it is some variation of it. Something that I do love is that the save operation is done by the context, not the object itself. So there is some type of separation.

However look at those functions like "awakeFromFetch" or "didSave", both operations are related with the data store, not a plain domain object. A proper Data Mapper pattern would allow you to define those operations for each persistent store, not unified in a single object.

**UPDATE:**

Funny enough one day after my answer I had to deal with an old CoreData based project and must come back to improve this answer. To make things clear, I do consider that "seems like a pattern" is not enough. For example, implementation of the facade and adapter patterns is quite similar, but you name them differently depending on how you use them.

Is Core Data implementing data mapper?

I must say that my "not quite" should have been "definitely not!"

I have just been very angry because I needed to rename some fields and later add new ones. Although I do know quite well how auto-migrations work with Core Data I forgot how annoying these are.

How many times do you need some new field, rename something, experiment until you get it right.... and every single tiny change requires a full blown database migration? With Data Mappers this never happens because domain objects are perfectly decoupled. You only touch the database to catch up with the domain objects after you finish some new feature. Core Data forces you to bind at every single moment every single detail of your domain objects.

Boy, how sweet life was until I forgot that "tiny" annoyance of Core Data being the exact opposite of what you can achieve with data mappers.

Comment: Listening to [the latest episode of the Ruby Rogues podcast](http://instaca.st/b/bfe), about [Ruby Object Mapper](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom), I found myself asking the same question. You're right that Core Data doesn't implement Data Mapper, however I think `NSManagedObjectContext` definitely implements [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html).